# maximum of a concave function in a minkowski sum

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let:

- $f(x,y)$ - a strictly-concave function, monotonically increasing in $x$ and $y$;
- $A,B$ - two compact and convex sets in the positive quadrant;
- $C$ - their Minkowski sum, $A+B$;
- $(x_A,y_A)$ - the point in $A$ that maximizes $f$ (it is unique since $f$ is strictly-concave);
- $(x_C,y_C)$ - the point in $C$ that maximizes $f$.

I am trying to prove (or find a reference to) the following conjecture:
$$x_C\geq x_A, \,\,\,\,\, y_C\geq y_A$$
I.e, if we Minkowski-add to $A$ a positive set ($B$), then the maximum point of $f$ moves only rightwards and/or upwards.

Is this conjecture true?

Maybe it is true if we assume that $f$ is symmetric, i.e, $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$?

Comment: Not true in general, something like $f(x,y) = x^{1/2}+y^{1/3}$ is a counterexample when the sets $A, B$ are of the form $x+y\le L$. The point being that the point of minimum trends down on the diagonal boundary to take advantage of greater values of $x$, which become more important.

Comment: @sandwich: This looks like an answer.

Comment: @sandwich I agree with you, but I don't think this function is a counterexample. $x$ does not actually trend down on the boundary, since the corresponding $y$ is a solution of $(S-y)^3=cy^2$ with $c=(3/2)^6$, and it is easy to see that this increases wrt $S$.

Comment: If it's worth anything, it can be proved that whenever $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$ and the sets are of the form $x+y\leq S$, then the conjecture is true.

Comment: I think I can prove that it is true whenever $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)$ and the sets are convex.